# Dependency in Math

Tags: tikz-pgf, dependencies

I trying to explain the orders of multiplication of algebraic expression. With MWE and `\usepackage{tikz-dependency}`, I failed to produce what I want though:

```
   $\begin{aligned}[t]          
 (a+b)^{2}&=\begin{dependency} [theme = simple]
   \begin{deptext}
      (\&a+\&b)(\&a+\&b)
  \end{deptext}
 \depedge{1}{3}{1}
 \depedge{1}{4}{2}
\depedge{2}{3}{3}
\depedge{2}{4}{4}
 \end{dependency}
  \\&=a^2+ab+ba+b^2
\\&=a^2+2ab+b^2
 \end{aligned} $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you want of course, but this works at least:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-dependency}

\begin{document}
  \[
\begin{aligned}[t]          
   (a+b)^{2}&=
    \begin{dependency}[theme = simple,baseline=-3pt]
    \begin{deptext}[inner xsep=0pt,column sep=0pt,nodes={inner sep=0pt}]
      $($\&$a$\&${}+{}$\&$b$\&$)($\&$a$\&${}+{}$\&$b$\&$)$ \\
    \end{deptext}
    \depedge{1}{6}{1}
    \depedge{1}{8}{2}
    \depedge{4}{6}{3}
    \depedge{4}{8}{4}
  \end{dependency}
  \\&=a^2+ab+ba+b^2
  \\&=a^2+2ab+b^2
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Dollars here are that very important!!!